# What is the difference between 'List' and 'Rawlist' when using Inquirer

Tags: npm, syntax, definition, inquirer

I'm using inquirer and I can either make a 'list' type or a 'rawlist' type.

My goal is to allow the user to select an item from an array of products from a sql database, but I am now curious what the difference between these two list types are? In the documentation, the definitions are:

List - {type: 'list'}
Take type, name, message, choices[, default, filter] properties. (Note that default must be the choice index in the array or a choice value)

and

Raw List - {type: 'rawlist'}
Take type, name, message, choices[, default, filter] properties. (Note that default must be the choice index in the array)

but I don't understand what they mean, or their difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like the difference is only in how the list is presented to the user. `list` presents them with a pointer that they can move up or down to make their selection, whereas `rawlist` presents them with a list to be selected by number. From what I can tell they behave identically in what they return.